# Php SQL if field.value = '?' include page.php else

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?
I am trying to include a certain page depending on the value of a field in database.

I have 2 tables to check,

if username appears in table.1 and field.units = days inlcude days.php

if username appears in table.1 and field.units = hours inlcude hours.php

if username appears in table.2 and field.units = days inlcude days.php

if username appears in table.2 and field.units = hours inlcude hours.php

```
   $username = $USER->firstname.'&nbsp;'.$USER->lastname;

    echo $username;

    $is_academic_result = mysql_query('SELECT * from holiday_entitlement_academic where employee = '.$username.'');
    $is_business_result = mysql_query('SELECT * from holiday_entitlement_business_manual where employee = '.$username.'');

    if(mysql_num_rows($is_academic_result) > 0){
    while($is_academic = mysql_fetch_array($is_academic_result)) {
    if ($is_academic['units'] == 'days'){include('days.php');}
    else if ($is_academic['units'] == 'hours'){include('hours.php');}
    }
    }

    else if(mysql_num_rows($is_business_result) > 0){
    while($is_business = mysql_fetch_array($is_business_result)) {
    if ($is_business['units'] == 'days'){include('days.php');}
    else if ($is_business['units'] == 'hours'){include('hours.php');}
    }
    }
```

Comment: It may not help with your answer, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: Do your usernames in the database really contain `&nbsp;` as in `$USER->firstname.'&nbsp;'.$USER->lastname`???

Comment: No usernames dont contain &nbsp; my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to do any of these operations in `while` loops, since there will only ever be one or zero results returned (you're checking the primary key, right?).

Secondly, your query isn't set up correctly - you're using single-quotes but never escaping them.

So, with that in mind, we do the following:

```
$is_academic_result = mysql_query('SELECT * from holiday_entitlement_academic where employee = \'' . $username . '\'');
$is_business_result = mysql_query('SELECT * from holiday_entitlement_business_manual where employee = \'' . $username . '\'');

if($is_academic = mysql_fetch_array($is_academic_result)) {
    switch($is_academic['units']) {
        case 'days':
            include_once('days.php');
            break;
        case 'hours':
            include_once('hours.php');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} else if ($is_business = mysql_fetch_array($is_business_result)) {
    switch($is_business['units']) {
        case 'days':
            include_once('days.php');
            break;
        case 'hours':
            include_once('hours.php');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE** You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

**EDIT** If you're unsure where the problem lies, you can always `echo` your query to make sure you're passing what you think you're passing to the database (more often than not, when a query isn't working, it's either this, or your logic is bad).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works great. Ill look at implementing PDO :)

Comment: @Codded notice the use of `include_once()` instead of `include()`. That will ensure that you don't include the same file (which may include function definitions) more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If your usernames really do contain `&nbsp;` (which seems like a poor design), you are missing quotes around the `$username` in your query.  As you have it now, there are syntax problems where you are leaving open a single quote at the end and not quoting the `$username` at all.

```
// Use double quotes on the string, and single around $username
$is_academic_result = mysql_query("SELECT * from holiday_entitlement_academic where employee = '$username'");
// Same thing...
$is_business_result = mysql_query("SELECT * from holiday_entitlement_business_manual where employee = '$username'");
```

These problems would be revealed if you did some error checking on the result resources:

```
if (!$is_academic_result) {
  // Query problem
  echo mysql_error();
}
// Same for the other query...
```